# Outliers for all numerical values to mean SAS

Tags: sas, outliers

I am working in SAS with a dataset with a lot of numeric values which I have standardised as follows:

```
 proc standard data=df mean=0 std=1
 out=df;       
 run;
```

Is there any easy way to deal with outliers (+/- 3standard deviation) for all numeric values? Ideally I would want to change all of those to + or - 3x standard deviation, or in worst case remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run through the data twice.  There are may ways you can adjust your output.  Here's a simple way using a datastep:

Assuming your dataset has a standardized variable called 'test':

```
Data adjusted;
set df;
if test > 3 then test=3;
if test < -3 then test =-3;
run;
```

just remember your new dataset will no longer have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this is that I have to name all the variables? I have several hundred, so I was looking for an option where I can perform one operation on all numerical variables.

Comment: i'm not sure I understand, can you show me a sample dataset?  We could easily address multiple variables with a data array.  Do you have hundreds of variables or hundreds of observations?

Comment: I have hundreds of numerical variables that are all standardised as shown in OP + a bunch of categorical variables.
What I want, is trim outliers of all the numerical variables. Arrays would also mean that I have to manually type in the name of all my variables, if I'm not wrong? That would be way to time-consuming.

Comment: the op doesn't tell me anything about your dataset.  Provide some sample data. AND no with an array we don't have to type in the names of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

No sample data provided so I generated 5 random variables with N(0,2) distribution for the purpose of demonstration for removing outliers from N(0,1).

If you have multiple columns to remove outliers from, you could create a macro or just loop through an array.

```
DATA have;
    INPUT var1 var2 var3 var4 var5;
    DATALINES;
-0.8458048655231136 -2.1737985573160485 -2.122482432573275 1.8746296707673902 -2.799009287469253
-1.9927731684115295 1.8230096873238637 0.5964656531490122 -1.6465532407305106 3.9430012045284184
0.0294083016125659 1.3877418982525658 -1.3398372120124733 -0.8195179339297752 4.742490300459201
-0.5215716306745832 -3.35412129416837 1.1558155344985737 -1.0073681302151822 2.425914724408619
-2.817574234024364 3.5161858163738424 -2.1822454739704744 0.060674570200235534 0.25898913069677443
-3.941905381717187 4.969013776451821 2.021891632999466 -1.1526212617289868 1.2864391876960568
;
run;

* variable of all columns to remove outliers from ;
%LET column_names=var1 var2 var3 var4 var5;

DATA want;
    SET have;
    ARRAY columns {*} &column_names.;
    DO i=1 to dim(columns);
        if columns[i]>3 then columns[i]=3;
        if columns[i]<-3 then columns[i]=-3;
    END;
    DROP i;
RUN;
```

Comment: Hi @Anna, is there a way to reverse the standardization  to regular value after I remove the outliers using your code? I would like to run statistics and plots.